# Why was Jim so enthusiastic about Dwight's Christmas party?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-office

In the most recent episode of [*The Office*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0386676/), [*Dwight Christmas*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2514850/), Jim very enthusiastically supports Dwight's Christmas party plans.  And he seems to genuinely enjoy the party, in all of its awkwardness.  Why?

This seemed entirely uncharacteristic of Jim.  Whenever he supports one of Dwight's unusual schemes, it's because Jim is trying to set Dwight up for failure. What was different about this time?

Comment: I thought the exact same thing. It was totally out of character for Jim...

Answer (score 8):

I think there was quite a bit of sarcasm/irony behind Jim's enthusiasm for Dwight's Christmas party.  Messing with Dwight is one of Jim's favorite hobbies, and with his impending departure to Philadelphia, he knows he won't get many more chances.  Hearing Dwight describe his family's Christmas traditions, Jim seems to realize that an office party organized around them will have tremendous train wreck appeal, so he enthusiastically supports the idea.  Jim's sarcasm is subtle, but it's clear in one line where he refers to Dwight's Christmas dishes and characters

> I'm not understanding the confusion.  Am I the only one who wants to try Hufflepuffs, and Schnauserhosen, and meet this Glennpickle guy?

It's also pretty clear in a later scene when Dwight appears as [Belsnickel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belsnickel), and Jim comments:

> So he's kind of like Santa, only dirty and worse.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Bill about the sarcasm. Jim was not so much interested in the party because he thought it would be good, but specifically because he thought it would be a crazy mess like most of his other experiences with Dwight’s life (like the B&B he stayed in).

I also agree that because Jim is expecting to leave the office, he may have been a little saddened that he would more than likely not be keeping in touch with Dwight and thus miss out on future craziness, so he wanted to have a last bash.

However, I think that there were a couple of more points that explain his behavior.

- He was hyped up about his trip to Philawhatever and the prospect of a new (and presumably more entertaining, not to mention lucrative) job. The endorphins and adrenaline would have made him a little less rational and a lot more excitable. Plus, he probably had a couple of egg-nogs. `;-)`
- He knew that leaving the office and Pam to jet off to Philly at Christmas time was pretty bad timing and he may have been perceived as selfish or more interested in work than friends and family, so by getting everybody wrapped up in Dwight’s craziness, he could distract them from his absence.

That said, I think Jim really did get caught up in the festivities, especially when he found a way to arrange things so that he could go to the meeting, but also stay for the party. This is probably due to his realization that his life is going to change and he will not be seeing these people whom he has grown fond of over the years. This nostalgia and sadness caused/allowed him to drop the sarcastic pretense and genuinely enjoy his last Christmas party at the The Office.